# How can I get all paid invoices from QuickBooks with quickbooks-ruby gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, synchronization, quickbooks

I am trying to get all paid invoices from QuickBooks that has been paid on specific period. How can I do this?

Or if I get all invoices on that period, how can I see which are was paid?

Comment: What is your question? what have you tried so far? What *specific* issue are you having? What error message are you seeing?

Comment: I got all invoices for specific period ->

`query = "SELECT * FROM Invoice WHERE MetaData.LastUpdatedTime >= '#{last_sync_time}'"`

How can I find which of them already was paid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer on IntuitDevelopers forum - [link](https://intuitdeveloper.lc.intuit.com/questions/1041980-how-can-i-get-if-invoice-was-paid-and-the-datetime-of-this-payment-using-your-api)

So, get all changed invoices for needed period

```
query = "SELECT * FROM Invoice WHERE MetaData.LastUpdatedTime >= '#{last_sync_time}'"
all_inv = []
@invoice_service.query_in_batches(query, per_page: 100) do |batch|
  batch.each do |invoice|
    all_inv << invoice
  end
end
```

Then check, which of them was paid since last sync.

```
all_inv.each do |inv|
  if inv.balance == 0 and inv.linked_transactions.any?
    my_local_invoice.update_attribute(:paid, true)
  end
end
```

That's worked for me.